# Why can't I set the margin of this wrapper?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that I can't figure out despite an hour of YouTube videos and looking on here. I have 4 divs inside of a wrapper. I would like the wrapper to have a top margin of 27px, and a left margin of 2%. For the bottom and right sides, I would like it to automatically expand to the edge of the screen. (Viewport)  What am I doing wrong here?

My code is below, and I have a fiddle at

However, the wrapper seems to do nothing and the div content starts at the edge of the screen no matter what I put in the CSS.

```css
.wrapper {
      margin: 27px auto auto 2%; // Does nothing
      position:absolute;
      }

#square1 { position:absolute; top:50%; width:50%;height:50%;left:0;background-color:blue}
#square2 { position:absolute; top:50%; width:50%;height:50%;left:50%;background-color:yellow}
#square3 { position:absolute; top:0; width:50%;height:50%;left:0;background-color:green}
#square4 { position:absolute; top:0; width:50%;height:50%;left:50%;background-color:red}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id='square1'></div>
<div id='square2'></div>
<div id='square3'></div>
<div id='square4'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "left margin of 2%" - **2% of what, exactly?** The viewport? Its parent element? The element's own width (using `border-box` or `content-box`)? The element's own height? Etc.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to set those of the viewport.

Comment: A couple things. `//` is not a line-comment in CSS. Use `/*`. Secondly, you gave your div an ID, not a class. Either change the HTML attribute to `class` or the CSS selector to `#wrapper`

Comment: What is `auto` supposed to mean for right and bottom..? Everything can't be relative to each other. Your squares are 50% height and then #wrapper has an auto height..?

Comment: @David Use `2vh` for "2% of viewport width". Avoid using `%` units in CSS because of the ambiguity and weird edge-case rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select an element with id (wrapper in your code) you need to use '#' instead of '.'. 
If you want to position something absolute, you need to position it direct/indirect parent relative, to let the browser know relative to which element place that absolutely positioned.

Also auto margins on right and left would center element (element is in the center if space from right and left are equal), but to span the element across you need to specify it's width. Keep in mind that margin in percents would be calculated from parent sizes.

Moreover if you have only absolutely position content inside element (wrapper) it would have zero height and you need to specify it explicitly.

As a side note, try to avoid repeting yourself. All squares have same properties, so combine it to new selector (square).

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 27px;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

#square1 {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  
  background-color: blue;
}

#square2 {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  
  background-color: yellow;
}

#square3 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  background-color: green;
}

#square4 {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id='square1' class="square"></div>
  <div id='square2' class="square"></div>
  <div id='square3' class="square"></div>
  <div id='square4' class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply, this works - except the squares still go beyond the viewport on the right side and bottom. This takes me back to where my problems began. Is this not possible to resolve? EDIT: I resolved the issue by giving the body 0 margin on all sides in addition to your code. Thank you

Comment: Also, it looks like you are new here. Welcome!

Answer (score 1):

1. selector is incorrect, should be id or class
2. made wrapper relative so child can be absolute otherwise they will stack to window not parent div
3. made parent div 100% height and width
4. There is no point of giving auto margin to right and bottom
5. CSS comment should be `/* */`

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: 27px auto auto 2%;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
}

#square1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue
}

#square2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: yellow
}

#square3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: green
}

#square4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id='square1'></div>
  <div id='square2'></div>
  <div id='square3'></div>
  <div id='square4'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

your wrapper is not class, it is id. Thats why you should use #wrapper. And it actually works:

[image]

just because of position: absolute you don't see the result, because position: absolute works so, it's mean you are using it in wrong way. [Read about position.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) The same result we can get with code below, or with [flexs](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [grids](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: 27px auto auto 2%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.square {
  width: 49.5%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#square1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#square2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#square3 {
  background-color: green;
}

#square4 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id='square1' class="square"></div>
<div id='square2' class="square"></div>
<div id='square3' class="square"></div>
<div id='square4' class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is works to give the left and top margin space, however the squares still overrun the right and bottom of the viewport. The squares should fill the container, but not go beyond the edge of the screen. What else do I need to do to prevent that?